# Manipulate versus Dynamic

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

I want to see a dynamic rendering of this surface as a function of the parameter `\[Alpha]`:

```
XSTsurface := 
RevolutionPlot3D[2 + ArcTan[α x], {x, -10, 10}, 
   RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}, Axes -> False, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3], 
   ColorFunction -> 
      Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[0.5 - 0.5 (2.0 + 0.5 ArcTan[x])]]];
```

This one works fine:

```
α = 0.7;
{Slider[Dynamic[α], {0, 1, 0.05}] , Dynamic[α] }
Dynamic[XSTsurface]
```

but this one doesn't:

```
Manipulate[XSTsurface, {α, 0, 1}]
```

What is it I am missing? I would have thought the two approaches should be pretty much equivalent (except for cosmetics)

Comment: `Manipulate` creates a new `SymbolName` (It's a derivative of `DynamicModule` after all). It can be seen in this code: `Manipulate[SymbolName[Unevaluated@s], {s, 0, 1}]`. If you want to make `XSTsurface` change when `α` changes, you need to make `XSTsurface` a function. That is, `XSTsurface[α_] := ...` and `Manipulate[XSTsurface[α], {α, 0, 1}]`.

Comment: With addition to @JHM comment, you can use `LocalizeVariables->False` too.